# Datepicker does not work on the modal. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using the bootstrap daterangepicker.js library, to generate a calendar in the text fields with the "date" class. I have a text field outside of the modal where it works perfectly, but the text fields with the class "date" that are in the modal does not work.

Why does this happen and what can I do?

```
$('.date').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "opens": "right",
})


<div ng-app="myApp">
 <input type='text' class='date'>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
    not works daterangepicker this field!
    <input type='text' class='date' id='date'>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(true)">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close('modalInstanceOne')">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <input type="button" value="Show modal" ng-click="showModal()" />
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8qbxtnaf/

Comment: I have posted an answer - let me know if it's what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I mix third-party widgets (UIbootstrap, jQueryUI, etc.) with angular code or templates, I always use custom directives. Here's a working example with the code you have provided:

**[Working DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8qbxtnaf/1/)**

The idea is to create a custom directive, and then attach it to your input elements - that way, whenever the element gets created via a structural angular directive or template, the link function gets called, and the widget gets instantiated. The problem that you were having was that the date input on the modal was being placed in the DOM **after** your `.daterangepicker()` was being called in your controller.

#### Directive + controller

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .directive("daterangepicker", function (){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $(element).daterangepicker({
          "singleDatePicker": true,
          "opens": "right",
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {
    // controller code here...
  });
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input type='text' class='date' daterangepicker>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      not works daterangepicker this field!
      <input type='text' class='date' id='date' daterangepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(true)">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close('modalInstanceOne')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="Show modal" ng-click="showModal()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your approach is, there is no controller in your modal. If you change your modal code to, change line

> div class="modal-body" ng-controller="MyCtrl"

it works.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" ng-controller="MyCtrl"> ---- ng-controller
    not works daterangepicker this field!
        <input type='text' class='date' id='date'>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(true)">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close('modalInstanceOne')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>
```